# Plotting 10 data sets on OpenTK

Tags: c#, opengl, glsl, shader, opentk

I have 10 sets of data saved in arrays. For example A1 = [1,2 ,3], A2 = [5,6,7]...etc. I am using OpenTk GameWindow to plot it as I have a big data set (10million+ per data set). For now I know how to plot 1 data set as following:

```
  public GraphWIndow (Data Dataset[0]) : base(800, 600, default, "Data Analyzer", GameWindowFlags.Default, default,4,0, default)
        {
            test= EditVertices(Dataset[0]);
        }

        private float[] EditVertices(List<float> list)
        {
            float[] list2d = new float[2*list.Count()];
            for(int i =0; i<list.Count(); i++)
            {
                list2d[2*i]=-1+ i*(((float)2/(float)list.Count()));
                list2d[2*i +1] =((float)(list[i]-list.Min())/(float)(list.Max()-list.Min()));
            }
            return list2d;
        }

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            CursorVisible = true;
            shader = new Shader("shader.vert", "shader.frag");
            shader.Use();
            VertexArrayObject = GL.GenVertexArray();
            VertexBufferObject = GL.GenBuffer(); 
            GL.BindVertexArray(VertexArrayObject);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, VertexBufferObject);
            GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, test.Count()*sizeof(float), test, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
            var vertexLocation = shader.GetAttribLocation("aPosition");
            GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(vertexLocation);
            GL.VertexAttribPointer( vertexLocation, 2, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 2*sizeof(float), 0);
            GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(0);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 0);
            GL.BindVertexArray(0);
            base.OnLoad(e);
        }

 protected override void OnRenderFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
        {
            GL.ClearColor(Color4.DarkBlue);
            GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);
            GL.BindVertexArray(VertexArrayObject);
            GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.LineStrip, 0, test.Count());
            GL.PointSize(10);
            SwapBuffers();
            base.OnRenderFrame(e);
        }
```

shader.vert

```
#version 400 core
in vec2 aPosition;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(aPosition, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

I kind of know how I will draw the 10 sets. I will just add an offset to every dataset and combine them in one array(test array) and then pass it to shader.vert. The thing is I don't know what to do with the x coordinates. I don't want to keep adding it to test array, which is shown in EditVertices function, as it will significantly increase its size especially that I am dealing with a huge size of data. Is there a way where I can pass x coordinates separately somehow but at the same time relate it to all data sets? as in they all share the same x coordinates but different Y values. I hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way where I can pass x coordinates separately somehow but at the same time relate it to all data sets?

Use 2 attributes of type `float`, one for the x coordinate and another one for the y coordinate:

```c
#version 400 core
in float aPositionX;
in float aPositionY;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(aPositionX, aPositionY, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

```cs
var vertexLocationX = shader.GetAttribLocation("aPositionX");
var vertexLocationY = shader.GetAttribLocation("aPositionY");
```

Now you can use the same X coordinate for all data sets. Create 1 array of vertex attribute data for the X coordinates:

```cs
float[] vertexX = new float[2*list.Count()];
for(int i =0; i < list.Count(); i++)
    vertexX[i] = (float)(-1 + i * 2/list.Count());
```

The array for the Y coordinates has to be created separately for each data set

```cs
float[] vertexY = new float[2*list.Count()];
for(int i =0; i < list.Count(); i++)
    vertexY[i] = (float)((vertexY[i]-list.Min() / (list.Max()-list.Min());
```

You have to create 2 separate [Vertex Buffer Objects](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Buffer_Object):

```cs
VertexBufferObjectX = GL.GenBuffer();
GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, VertexBufferObjectX);
GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vertexX.Count()*sizeof(float), vertexX, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);

VertexBufferObjectY = GL.GenBuffer();
GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, VertexBufferObjectY);
GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vertexY.Count()*sizeof(float), vertexY, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
```

And you have to adapt the specification of the [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object):

```
VertexArrayObject = GL.GenVertexArray();            
GL.BindVertexArray(VertexArrayObject);

GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, VertexBufferObjectX);
GL.VertexAttribPointer(vertexLocationX, 1, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 0, 0);
GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, VertexBufferObjectY);
GL.VertexAttribPointer(vertexLocationY, 1, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 0, 0);

GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(vertexLocationX);
GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(vertexLocationY);

GL.BindVertexArray(0);
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks!